# mail function returns false

Tags: php, email

It has been asked multiple times here, but I can't find the answer.
I've tried to add headers etc but nothing seems to work.
My code returns "false" everytime I try to send the mails.

```
    <?php   
    if(isset($_GET['action'])=='submitfunc') {
$EmailTo = prep($sObj->email);
$Subject = "The reason why your submission got rejected.";
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@website.com>' . "\r\n";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body.= "Message: ";
$Body.= $Message;

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo,$Subject,$Body,$headers);

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=succes.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
}else { ?>

  <div class="emailrejection">
                <form method="post" action="?action=submitfunc">

Dear <?php prep($sObj->username); ?>,   <br>            
                <textarea placeholder="Describe why the image got rejected...." name="Message" rows="3" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea> <br>
                All the best,,<br>
                Moderator <?php prep($uObj->username); ?><br>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="No + send message" class="btn btn-large btn-danger"  />
            </form>
  </div>
```

I think the error is in line 3.

```
$EmailTo = prep($sObj->email);
```

If I replace this with: 
`$EmailTo = "myemail.gmail.com";` everthing works fine.

If I echo $EmailTo it also works fine. Why can't this be handeled in the mail function?

Comment: It might and might not be because of your code. Best way to be clear about this is to try with **PHPMailer**. If you get `false` from `PHPMailer` - then it's up to your MTA / sendmail binary.  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Is the code executed in localhost ?

Comment: No, it's executed on a server. I've added more information to my post. The error is somewhere in the $EmailTo part.

Comment: So, what does this `prep()` function do and where is it? That isn't a core PHP function; that I know. So, I can't test this for you. Other than that, the rest of your code looks fine to me. Ping me if you have other info; I won't be keeping this tab open.